# how to click on a href link using Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, button, click

I'm using Selenium and Python to try and click on button on a web page as bellow:

```
<div id="home" class="sc-gKAaRy bGevZe"><h1 tabindex="-1" id="home_children_heading" class="sc-fujyAs fxSjMq">Vérification</h1>
<p id="home_children_body" class="sc-pNWdM hbrIBL">Veuillez résoudre l’énigme pour que nous sachions que vous n’êtes pas un robot.</p>
<a href="#" aria-describedby="descriptionVerify" id="home_children_button" class="sc-bdnxRM gonizE sc-kEqXSa duYBxC">Suivant</a>
<div id="descriptionVerify" class="Home__StyledHiddenAnnouncement-sc-lzg094-0 kfyjkn">
Défi visuel.Les utilisateurs de lecteurs d'écran doivent utiliser le défi audio ci-dessous.</div></div>
```

I try many solution as click by Xpath and href but no one is work, can you help me please ?
here is the code i try to use it:

```
xPath = '//*[@id="home_children_button"]'
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xPath).click()

#With other Xpath

xPath = 'xPath = "//input[contains(@type,'submit')][contains(@id,'home_children_button')][contains(.,'Suivant')]"'
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xPath).click()
```

I need your help , Please!

Comment: Does it throw any error stating the element was not found? If yes, then possibly your xpath is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If this id `home_children_button` is unique in `HTMLDOM`, then please try with below xpath :

```
//a[@id='home_children_button']
```

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='home_children_button']").click()
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='home_children_button']"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='home_children_button']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='home_children_button']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Answer (score 1):

You should write like this

```
xpath = browser.find_element_by_xpath('TYPE THE XPATH')
xpath.click()
```